# Begginner issue with prime number generating

Tags: objective-c

Now I am not asking for a full answer as I could probably find a ready answer somewhere after digging but I just need a small hint of what Im doing wrong. My problem is that although I do get Prime numbers in my output there are multiple consecutive repetitions of the same number. 
Hope someone can subtly guide me and thanks to anyone who offers help :)

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: try adding  `break` statement into the scope of second `if` statement so that you would jump out of internal `for` loop.

Comment: Consider the case where x is 5.  Your inner loop will execute three times with y equal to 2, 3, and 4.  Each time through, your mod test will fail and print the value of x.

Comment: Well that worked perfectly big thanks !!